# Azure Redis Cache error No connection is available to service this operation:

Tags: azure, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to use Azure Redis cache in my MVC 4.6 app but getting connection errors. This is the error:

> No connection is available to service this operation: GET
>   c7fc43f3-47c4-43cb-94ff-50527b1cda0c_TokenCache; It was not possible
>   to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected
>   multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. ConnectTimeout; IOCP:
>   (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=2,Free=4093,Min=2,Max=4095), Local-CPU: 100%

My web.config has:

`<add key="ida:CacheConnection" value="myCache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=bpPQX6jeocNjyX1FqrvVztGMQqjekXbUXFjGkiZOyCE=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,connectTimeout=30,syncTimeout=3000,ConnectRetry=3" />`

My packages.config has:

```
<package id="StackExchange.Redis" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I followed this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache) article to configure Aazure Redis server and client.

I tried to use client side cmd line tool to verify the connection even that is not working. Not giving me any sign of success or failure. This is my command:

```
C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-cli -h "myCache.redis.cache.windows.net" -a bpPQX= -p 6379
```

I tried -p 6380 as well but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your Redis cache via Redis CLI after disable the Only SSL Access?

Comment: Nope. Non-SSL access is enabled from portal. Sill the cli gives me no response.

Comment: Does your network have any outbound connection restrictions?  I tried using the info you gave above and here is the output I got...  

  redis-cli.exe -h "myCache.redis.cache.windows.net" -p 6379  

  myCache.redis.cache.windows.net:6379> auth wrongpassword  

  (error) ERR invalid password

Comment: Yes I am behind corporate firewall. But don't know about restrictions. Can you please provide me with terse information about waiving off/relaxing bits which I need to tell to my security team? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set in Azure Portal: `Non-SSL port (6379) enabled`.

Try to connect to port `6379`, using `CLI`. 
I don't think that Redis-CLI can connect to SSL port (6380)

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your Redis Cache resource blade's **`Advanced Settings`** in the Azure portal, set **`Allow access only via SSL`** to **`No`** and Save the setting.

You should be able to connect to your Redis cache via Redis CLI:

```
redis-cli -h "myCache.redis.cache.windows.net" -a bpPQX=
```

`-p 6379` can be optional because the default Non-SSL port for Azure Redis Cache is 6379.

[image]

Reference: [StackExchange.Redis Configuration Doc](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Configuration.md)

Comment: Nothing changed. Still no response in client.

Comment: Have you try Diagnose and Solve Problem in Azure portal?

Comment: No errors and warning in the CLI. It just stays. Yes, this particular issue is not stated. Also, if i try using console in azure portal UI, i get error if i run basic command like `set message "hello"`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but in my case it was because a private endpoint had been setup on the Redis instance and this blocks all non-local connections. Check if you have a private endpoint setup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your connection string

   - Set abortConnect to false
   - Adjust your syncTimeout and asyncTimeout as needed.
   - If you are using a secure TLS connection set the ssl=True,sslprotocols=tls12 in your configuration to force it to the latest version.
2. Upgrade your StackExchange.Redis nuget package to latest if you can.
3. Set the config option for ReconnectRetryPolicy in your C# code to be ExponentialRetry
   https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html#reconnectretrypolicy

   ```
   private static readonly Lazy<ConfigurationOptions> configOptions  = new Lazy<ConfigurationOptions>(() =>
   {
       var connections = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["redis-connection"].ConnectionString;
       var configOptions = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(connections);

       configOptions.ClientName = "MyApp-RedisCacheProvider";
       //configOptions.SyncTimeout = 100000; // don`t do this in code, set it in your connection string
       //configOptions.AbortOnConnectFail = false; // don`t do this in code, set it in your connection string

       /*
        * The default is LinearRetry which can cause congestion at virtually the same time on multiple parallel threads.
        * Use ExponentialRetry so that a degree of randomness is used in the timing across multiple threads.
        */
       configOptions.ReconnectRetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(5000, 10000);

       return configOptions;
   });

    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> connection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(
            () => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configOptions.Value));
   ```
4. Implement IDisposable to dispose the object after its use

   ```
        public void Dispose()
        {
            try {
                if (connection.IsValueCreated)
                {
                    connection.Value.Dispose(); 
                }
            } catch { }
        }
   ```